# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 mac

Tags: c++

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

This is the error message. I'm a C++ beginner, i use Sublime Text 3 to write the following code. I don't know how to deal with it, I didn't install Xcode in my macbook. please help!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool StringContain(string &a,string &b)
{
    const int p[26] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59,61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101};
    int f = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i)
    {
        int x = p[a[i] - 'A'];
        if (f % x)
        {
            f *= x;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); ++i)
    {
        int x = p[b[i] - 'A'];
        if (f % x)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `main` function, this is the entry point to your executable.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool StringContain(string &a,string &b)
{
    const int p[26] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59,61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101};
    int f = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i)
    {
        int x = p[a[i] - 'A'];
        if (f % x)
        {
            f *= x;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); ++i)
    {
        int x = p[b[i] - 'A'];
        if (f % x)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

If you are trying to build a standalone object, you need to examine the line that compiles it.